# Unresolved Referece : LayoutParams on Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have problem to convert our function from Java Language to Kotlin. I used `AS 3.2.1`

Here my function on Java

```
private class ImageViewFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {
    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        final LayoutParams lp = new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

and in kotlin as bellow

```
private inner class ImageViewFactory : ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {
    override fun makeView(): View {
        val imageView = ImageView(this@MainActivity)
        imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

        val lp =
            ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        imageView.layoutParams = lp

        return imageView
    }
}
```

problem comes from `ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams`, on Java its work well. But unfortunately Kotlin doesn't recognized these function.

Here my Java Apps gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':card-slider')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

And bellow from my Kotlin Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.cardslider:card-slider:0.3.0'
```

It shown syntax error on Android Studio `Unresolved references : LayoutParams`

I'm not sure what happened on it. Please let me know what I missed. Thanks

Comment: Kindly check my answer :)

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think ImageSwitcher doesn't have inner class LayoutParams
 so you can't directly access that so just use his parent layout that in this case is FrameLayout

For solve the problem just replace this line

```
val lp = ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

With

```
val lp = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

Because [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher)

```
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.widget.FrameLayout
               ↳    android.widget.ViewAnimator
                   ↳    android.widget.ViewSwitcher
                       ↳    android.widget.ImageSwitcher
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you want to convert `Java` to `Kotlin` but can't resolve the reference. Just take a look at the import section of `Java` file, then you can find which one should be imported in `Kotlin` file.

For your question, the `LayoutParams` is imported from `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

[image]

[image]